# Issues Parsing XML data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I am having some difficulty trying to parse some shipping details (sent to us ax XML) in SQL Server.

The XML structure is as follows:

```
<Parent>
    <ShipmentNotice>
        <VendorSKU>ABC123</VendorSKU>
            <SerialNumbers>
                <string>AAAABBBB</string>
                <string>11112222</string>
                <string>CCCCDDDD</string>
                <string>33334444</string>
            </SerialNumbers>
        </VendorSKU>
    </ShipmentNotice>
    <ShipmentNotice>
        <VendorSKU>123ABC</VendorSKU>
            <SerialNumbers>
                <string>EEEEFFFF</string>
                <string>55556666</string>
                <string>GGGGHHHH</string>
                <string>77778888</string>
            </SerialNumbers>
        </VendorSKU>
    </ShipmentNotice>
</Parent>
```

Essentially each instance of a product being sent has two `<string>` tags per instance (AAAABBBB, 11112222).  What I am looking to do is parse through the XML and create a row for each `<string>` pair based on the VendorSKU I provide.

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT
   #ShippingRequests.[xmlcontent].value('(Parent/ShipmentNotice/VendorSKU)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS VendorSKU,
   #ShippingRequests.[xmlcontent].value('(Parent/ShipmentNotice/SerialNumbers/string)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS ICCID, 
    #ShippingRequests.[xmlcontent].value('(Parent/ShipmentNotice/SerialNumbers/string)[2]', 'varchar(max)') AS IMEI 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        StoreID, CAST(REPLACE(CAST([RequestData] as NVARCHAR(MAX)), '<User=/>', '') AS XML) AS xmlcontent 
     FROM 
        #ShippingRequests) #ShippingRequests
--CROSS APPLY #ShippingRequests.xmlcontent.nodes('(Parent/ShipmentNotice/SerialNumbers/string)') AS t(c)
WHERE 
    #ShippingRequests.xmlcontent.value('(Parent/ShipmentNotice/VendorSKU)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = 'ABC123'
```

Running this without the `CROSS APPLY`, two issues arise:

1. I only get the first `<string>` pair
2. A result only shows if VendorSKU ABC123 is part of the first `<ShipmentNotice>` tag.  If VendorSKU ABC123 the second `<ShipmentNotice>` in the next XML to parse, then nothing shows.

Running this with the `CROSS APPLY`, I get a ton of duplicates.

How can I get this query to run for all `<string>` pairs and run regardless of where the VendorSKU shows in the XML?

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using? Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL? Please tag or mention in post.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way. Shred the XML data on `<ShipmentNotice>` elements, and apply `VendorSKU` checking on the shredded XML instead of the original XML column, like so :

```
.......
CROSS APPLY #ShippingRequests.xmlcontent.nodes('(Parent/ShipmentNotice)') AS t(c)
WHERE c.value('(VendorSKU)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = '123ABC'
```

Note that the XML sample posted is not well-formed as it has too many `VendorSKU` closing tags. This is a [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/1595) example after removing the excess closing tags :

```
declare @ShippingRequests TABLE(StoreID int, RequestData XML)
insert into @ShippingRequests values(1, '<Parent>
    <ShipmentNotice>
        <VendorSKU>ABC123</VendorSKU>
            <SerialNumbers>
                <string>AAAABBBB</string>
                <string>11112222</string>
                <string>CCCCDDDD</string>
                <string>33334444</string>
            </SerialNumbers>
    </ShipmentNotice>
    <ShipmentNotice>
        <VendorSKU>123ABC</VendorSKU>
            <SerialNumbers>
                <string>EEEEFFFF</string>
                <string>55556666</string>
                <string>GGGGHHHH</string>
                <string>77778888</string>
            </SerialNumbers>
    </ShipmentNotice>
</Parent>')
SELECT
c.value('(VendorSKU)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS VendorSKU,
c.value('(SerialNumbers/string)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS ICCID, 
c.value('(SerialNumbers/string)[2]', 'varchar(max)') AS IMEI 
FROM
(
   SELECT 
   StoreID, CAST(REPLACE(CAST([RequestData] as NVARCHAR(MAX)), '<User=/>', '') AS XML) AS xmlcontent 
   FROM 
   @ShippingRequests
) 
#ShippingRequests
CROSS APPLY #ShippingRequests.xmlcontent.nodes('(Parent/ShipmentNotice)') AS t(c)
WHERE c.value('(VendorSKU)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = '123ABC' --'ABC123'
```

**output :**

```
| VendorSKU |    ICCID |     IMEI |
|-----------|----------|----------|
|    123ABC | EEEEFFFF | 55556666 |
```